# extract data from xmllist using e4x Flex 4

Tags: xml, printing, e4x

here is a simplification of my problem. I'm trying to extract the number '11' below, but none of my trace statements print anything but empty strings.  When I examine the list variable in the debugger, it is not null.  Thanks!

```
var list:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection();
var x:XML = <property name="id" value="11" />
list.addItem(x);
trace ("list " + list);
trace ("list 0   " + list[0]);
trace ("value  " + list[0].(@value));
trace ("value  " + list[0].(@value).toString());
trace ("value  " + list[0].(@value).value);
trace ("value  " + list[0].(@value).toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
list[0].(trace(@value));
```

and this works:

```
list[0].(myCaptureValueFunction(@value));
```